# BeautifulSoup4でブログの画像を取得する際に高速化を行いたい。

Tags: python, macos, python3

Mac OS Sierra
Ver 10.12.1
Python3

取得するページはこちらです。
http://www.keyakizaka46.com/s/k46o/diary/member/list?ima=0000&page=0&rw=20&cd=member&ct=02

pageを回すだけでページを巡回することができます。
現在のコードがこちらです。

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
from urllib import request
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
import os.path
import os
import time
import re 


# url先の画像を保存する関数
  def download(url):
   url = url
   headers = {
              "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) 
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0",
                  }
print(url)
req = request.Request(url, None, headers)
img = request.urlopen(req)
localfile = open(os.path.basename(url), 'wb')
localfile.write(img.read())
img.close()
localfile.close()


 # shutterstockの画像検索結果を保存
 # アクセス先遷移
 #par_url = 'http://www.keyakizaka46.com/s/k46o/diary/member/list?
site=k46o&ima=0000&ct=17'
 #imoはページ数 ctはメンバー数
 # def page_info(url):
 #     url = url + "?ima=" + str("0".zfill(4)) + 
"&page=8&rw=20&cd=member&ct=02"
#     return url

 def main():

    for i in range(0,100):
        try:
            url = "http://www.keyakizaka46.com/s/k46o/diary/member/list?ima=0000&page={}&rw=20&cd=member&ct=02".format(str(i))
        # urlアクセス
            res = request.urlopen(url)
       # beautifulsoupでパース
          soup = BeautifulSoup(res.read(),"html.parser")
        # ページに存在するimgタグを検索
        for link in soup.find_all('img'):
       # 画像URLを取得


            img_url = link.get('src')
            if img_url.netloc == "http://www.keyakizaka46.com" and img_url.path.startswith("/images/"):
                print(img_url)

        # ローカルに画像をダウンロード
                download(img_url)
                time.sleep(10)
    except HTTPError as e:
        print('Error code: ', e.code)
    except URLError as e:
        print('Error code: ', e.code)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

こちらのプログラムを起動して放置したところ２時間半程度で４００枚程度の画像しか保存ができませんでした。
こちらの処理を高速化するためにはどのようにすればよいでしょうか教えてください。

Comment: まずはボトルネックを探すために計測（プロファイリング）してみてはどうでしょうか？
じつはプログラムが問題ではなくてネットワーク環境だったり、ハードウェアの問題であるかもしれないので。

Answer (score 1):

単純に高速化を測るのであれば `time.sleep(10)` としているところは10秒待ってるので、それを減らせば速くはなるでしょう。

ただし適度に間隔をあけてアクセスすることは重要なので気をつけてください。最低でも1秒待つようにしましょう。 願わくばページのアクセスする時も間隔をあけた方が良いです。最悪訴えられます。

```
# urlアクセス
res = request.urlopen(url)
# 1ページアクセスしたら間隔をあける
time.sleep(1)
```

https://speakerdeck.com/amacbee/pythondezuo-ruwebkuroraru-men